# Debugging in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, debugging

I'm developing a web-application using HTML5 canvas and I need to debug in mobile browsers.

Normally I'm using firebug in Firefox and the built-in developer tools in Chromium for this, but I need to do some of the same on the iPhone and on Android-based phones, like the HTC Hero.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug lite is probably your best bet. Take a look at this bookmarklet which combines firebug lite with a bunch of other useful tools for mobile: [Mobile Perf Bookmarklet](http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/mobileperfbkm.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre), I tested it on Android 2.2 (Samsung) and it worked. It still has some hiccups, but you can use it for remote javascript logging and debugging the DOM.